# Can I use node-config to load configuration settings from config files created by other libraries such as sequelize-cli?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli, node-config

**The Problem**

In my `/config` directory, I have two configuration files.  One is created by `sequelize-cli` and contains database settings for development, test, and production.  The other is a configuration file used by `node-config`.

I find myself having to duplicate database configuration in the two files in order to make them available for e.g. migrations, as well as for calls to `config.get('some_config')` from within my application code.  By default the two files look like this:

***config.json***

```
    {
      "development": { 
        "database": "db-name",
        "username": "db-username",
        "password": "db-password",
        ...
      },
      "test": { ... },
      "production": { ... }
    }
```

***development.json***

```
    {
      "app": {
        "name": "app-name"
      },
      "dbconf": {
        "database": "db-name",
        "username": "db-username",
        "password": "db-password",
        ...
      }
    }
```

**Desired Outcome**

Instead of duplicating database configuration across different files, I want to I want to use `node-config` to load settings from the file that `sequelize init` created (`config.json`).

This does not appear to be possible, and `node-config` is unable to read settings from `config.json`.

Alternately, I could set `development.json` as the config file for `sequelize-cli`.

This works, but only if all the database information is at the top level of the object, and I would like the flexibility of nesting the information.

Is there a way to make this work, and if not, what is a better approach?